# Location list, preview window, autocompletion

Tags: autocompletion

I have the following problem. If the location list is open (e.g., by Syntastic) and some other plugin opens a preview window (e.g., YCM or jedi-vim), the cursor goes in the location list. Example:

[image]

After selecting "abort":

[image]

It happens in vim, neovim and gvim.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

UPDATE: it seems the problem was caused by MiniBufExpl.

Comment: report as issue to either syntastic or YCM/jedi-vim?

Comment: I don't think it's a plugin-specific issue, but i will do. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to rule them out is to try the same scenario without those plugins.